# how to use 3x3 gaussian filter correctly

Tags: java, opencv, gaussian, edge-detection

I am following a tutorial in image processing and it says the following

```
From the gray-scale image, a Gaussian image pyramid PGauss is
computed by firstly applying a 3× 3 Gaussian filter to the image
```

I know how to down and up sample an image using `PyrUp` and `PyrDown`. but i do not how to use or apply 3x3 gaussian filter!

i read some postes and i followed them, and they suggested to use
     `ImgProc.getGaussianKernel(p1,p2,p3)`

the problem i faced when i used `ImgProc.getGaussianKernel(p1,p2,p3)` are

1-i could not specify the type as CV_32 or CV_64, beacause when i specify the parameter3 as `ImgProc.CV_32` it is always underscred with red line?

2-i used the `getGaussianKernel` with only two parameters the size and the sigma, and when i ran this step and wrote the Mat returned from it to the hard drive, i found the image is empty despite it has size. why that is happening?

please let me know how to use 3x3 gaussian filter correctly

**Update**:

can i use `ImgProc.blur(.....)` to smooth the image instead of `ImgProc.getGaussianKernel(p1,p2,p3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really should look at the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#getGaussianKernel(int,%20double)) before asking , also: [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#filter2D(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))
 ..

```
int kernelSize = 3; // 3x3 filter
int resultType = CvType.CV_32F; // CvType, not Imgproc !
double sigma = 1.2; // whatever you choose.

Mat kernel = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(kernelSize, sigma, resultType);

// now apply the filter:
Mat filtered = new Mat();
Imgproc.filter2D(image, filtered, CvType.CV_32F, kernel);
```

[GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#GaussianBlur(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Size,%20double,%20double)) does the same as the code above, blur() is using a box-filter, not a gaussian one.

Comment: thank you. but would you please tell me how to apply that filter, you created in your answer, on an image?

Comment: oh, sorry, ofc. forgot the most important part ;)